# Is there a way in MySQL to get a count of members from one year that have also registered in previous years?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I have two tables. One is for club names and the other is for registrations that also stores clubs. The tables look like the following:

Registration:

```
| MemberID |FName |CLUBID | Year
| 24356    |John  |2      | 2014
| 24356    |John  |2      | 2015
| 24378    |Dave  |3      | 2014
| 24356    |John  |2      | 2016
| 24378    |Dave  |3      | 2015
| 24378    |Dave  |3      | 2018
| 24356    |John  |2      | 2018
| 41342    |James |4      | 2018
```

Clubs:

```
|Name   |CLUBID 
|Bears  |2      
|Tigers |3      
|Lions  |4
```

I have the following code that works perfectly for getting the total number of members in each club:

```
SELECT
Name,
Clubs.CLUBID as CID,
(SELECT COUNT(MemberID) FROM Registration WHERE CLUBID = CID AND Year = 2018) AS Total
FROM `Clubs`
```

I want two other columns, similar to my column aliased as 'Total', one where it counts all of the 2018 registrations that have records from previous years and calls the column alias 'returning' and another column that counts all of the registrations that have just one registration for 2018 and no previous years and calls the column alias 'new'.

Answer (score 0):

You need the information about the first appearance of the name.  This requires joining in additional information:

```
SELECT c.ClubId, c.Name,
       COUNT(*) as Total,
       SUM( rc.minyear = 2018 ) as news,
       SUM( rc.minyear < 2018 ) as returning
FROM Clubs c LEFT JOIN
     Registration r
     ON c.ClubId = r.ClubId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r2.clubid, r2.MemberId, MIN(r2.year) as minyear
      FROM Registration r2
      GROUP BY r2.clubid, r2.MemberId
     ) rc
     ON rc.ClubId = r.ClubId AND rc.MemberId = r.MemberId
WHERE r.year = 2018
GROUP BY c.ClubId, c.Name ;
```

Comment: It says unknown column r2.name. Also, is that supposed to be 'Name' and then switch to 'name'? Or are they both supposed to be capitalized?

Comment: @sjw0525 . . . The subquery should actually be using member id.  As for capitalization, I usually keep my names in lowercase, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I saw that... I swapped it to MemberID.  It just hangs indefinitely now

Comment: You don't *need* to know about the first appearance of the name. It's enough to know to ignore names with no prior appearance- although the implementation of that inversion of the logic may be less performant

Comment: @sjw . . . The query should not hang, unless your data is pretty big.

Comment: The data is large because it is pulling a lot of memberships, but my original query works fine